# Add label to horizontal line annotation in Superset chart

Tags: apache-superset

I see how to add a horizontal line to an Apache Superset chart, but can't figure out how to display the label on the chart.  I want users to be able to see it without having to mouseover the chart.

Here's an example with the Games per Genre over time demo chart.  My annotation:

[image]

That gets the line to display at 100, but its label - Target Number of Games - is not visible:
[image]

Is there a way to get the label to display just above or below its line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per a moderator in the Apache Superset Slack message board, this is not currently possible as of v1.5.0.